# Navigate to certain slider element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have multiple sliders on my page, I am using a plugin called [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/). On page load I have all my class `newsarticle` hidden but show the first parent as you may be able to see below my sliders are split into years; year2003, year2004 etc.

I have everything on a single page, therefore a URL such as wwww.example1.com/year2004.html wouldn't work, but I know I can use the following method:

`www.example1.com/index.html#2003_concorde`

This jumps to that ID on the page, which is great, however as I have my other sliders hidden by default if I try to jump to the following URL:

`www.example1.com/index.html#2004_firefox` or `www.example1.com/index.html#year_2004`

This will not show the corresponding div, as well because it is hidden by default and is only unhidden when I use my range slider.

Is there a way that I can successfully navigate to a hidden element on my page? Will I have to insert some JS logic to unhide these sliders?

Can somebody perhaps give me a generic example of how this works?

Appreciate any help in advance.

### UPDATE:

#### What I have tried so far

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
     if(window.location.href.indexOf("#digitl2004")) {
       // hide elements
                $('.newsarticle').hide();
                  $('.most_popular_contents').hide();                

                //show elements
                $('#digitl2004').fadeIn('fast');
                  $('.news_content_2004').fadeIn('fast');               


                // bg image change
                var image = $('#maincontent');
                image.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                image.css('background-image','url(images/facebook.jpg)');
                image.fadeIn('fast');
                });    }
      });
 </script>
```

However this has worked to no avail! I'm no expert on JS but I envision it can work the way I have tried above, or if I can get the JS to change the slider value depending on URL inserted i.e. if digitl2004 is in the URL then the range slider value will change to 2004.

index.html

```
<div id="digitl2003" class="newsarticle year2003"> <!-- Start Year 2003 -->
    <div class="newsyear">
        <h2 class="timeline_year">2003</h2>
    </div> <!-- End Div News Year -->
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li>
                <div class="newselement" id="2003_safari">
                <h3 class="timeline_heading">Safari Browser launched</h3>

                        <p class="timeline_content">On January 7th 2003, at Macworld in San Francisco, Steve Jobs announces that Apple are releasing their own web browser, Safari. Subsequent releases of the browser follow with the full version 1.0 release on June 23 2003.</p>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_browser#Safari_1" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a></p>
                            <div class="newsshareicons">
                               <div class="wrapper">

                                <img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_fb" alt="Share on Facebook" title="Share on Facebook"/>
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=In%202003%20Steve%20Jobs%20announces%20that%20Apple%20are%20releasing%20their%20own%20browser%20Safari%20#DIGI.T.L." target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_twitter" alt="Share on Twitter" title="Share on Twitter"/></a>
                                <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_linkedin" alt="Share on LinkedIn" title="Share on Linekdin"/></a>
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/googleplus_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_googleplus" alt="Share on Google+" title="Share on Google+"/></a>
                               </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
                           </div> <!-- End News Share Icon --> 

                </div> <!-- End News Element -->
            </li>  <!-- End List -->

            <li>
                <div class="newselement" id="2003_concorde">
                <h3 class="timeline_heading">The end of Concorde</h3>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Concorde ends three decades of supersonic travel when, on 26th November 2003 the last Concorde lands at its new home at Filton Airfield; the airfield where it was built.</p>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Source: <a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/bristol/3238674.stm" target="_blank">BBC News</a></p>
                </div>
                  <div class="newsshareicons">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_fb" alt="Share on Facebook" title="Share on Facebook"/>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=Concorde%20ends%20three%20decades%20of%20supersonic%20travel%20on%2026th%20November%202003%20#DIGI.T.L." target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_twitter" alt="Share on Twitter" title="Share on Twitter"/></a>
                            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                            <img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_linkeidn" alt="Share on LinkedIn" title="Share on Linekdin"/>
                            <img src="images/googleplus_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_googleplus" alt="Share on Google+" title="Share on Google+"/>
                       </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
                </div> <!-- End News Share Icon --> 
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="newselement" id="2003_genome">
                <h3 class="timeline_heading">Human Genome Project completed</h3>

                        <p class="timeline_content">In April 2003 it is announced that the project to sequence the human genome is complete. The mapping is now close to 100% complete, with only very small gaps left which are considered too costly to fill in at this point.</p>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Source: <a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/sci/tech/2940601.stm" target="_blank">BBC News</a></p>
                </div>
                 <div class="newsshareicons">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                <img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_fb" alt="Share on Facebook" title="Share on Facebook"/>
                                <img src="images/twitter_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_twitter" alt="Share on Twitter" title="Share on Twitter"/>
                                <img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_linkeidn" alt="Share on LinkedIn" title="Share on Linekdin"/>
                                <img src="images/googleplus_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_googleplus" alt="Share on Google+" title="Share on Google+"/>
                               </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
                </div> <!-- End News Share Icon --> 
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div><!-- End Year2003 -->
```

Js/js.js

```
 $('.newsarticle').hide();
 $('.newsarticle:first-child').show();
```

Comment: @mdesdev well at the start I hide all `div` with the class `newsarticles` and show only the first child and I use a range slider to navigate between the years as it is only a one page design thus far. I ideally want to be to type into the URL www.example1.com/index#digitl2004 and it hides all newsarticles once more and shows the ID of the div digitl2004

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/2hsGM/) going in right direction?

Comment: @mdesdev thanks but no this is not what I am looking to achieve. I want jquery to be able to read my URL and show and hide content according to the URL just how I achieve my slider method once a new value is found it will change the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following plugin to detect hash changes: https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange

Comment: I think perhaps you are misunderstanding me, what I really want is a way to query my URL, if anything after the domain is what is specified, then hide this and show that for example.

Comment: thanks for a better answer will up vote as you've pointed me into a good direction. will research now and if suitable for what I need will accept this answer